# Solve "400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Bad Request" }" issue for google adsense management api

Tags: java, adsense

i currently use the google adsense management api template from github for java and i got this error:

Listing all AdSense accounts

400 Bad Request{"error" : "invalid_grant","error_description" : "Bad Request"}

I already tried to recreate the client_secret.json, but this did not help

Comment: Please, add the code of the application to try to understand more.
Also log stacktrace if it is possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment there is a link to the source code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/java/v1.x